# moment ISO 8601 strings

Tags: momentjs

How do I use moment JS to convert this  ISO 8601 date format: `20160317T093555,100` to an actual moment object?

What I get is an invalid date. Changing it to `2016-03-17T09:35:55.210` works fine but thats not what I get from the server.

According to http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/ under Supported ISO 8601 strings this date format should be supported.

Comment: Yes, but still the same.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho Seems like momentjs does only support extended ISO format. You need to file an issue.

Comment: @DavinTryon This is pretty standard and valid. A parser not able to parse it is not standards compliant.

Comment: @Michael-O but if you see their documentation momentjs should support short iso-format, or is it something that has disappeared with updates?

Comment: Yes, this is from the [parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) docs: `20130208T080910,123      # Short date and time up to ms, separated by comma`

Comment: @DavinTryon what does that mean?

Comment: It means that this format *should* be supported to parse.

Comment: This works for me: `moment('20160317T093555,100')`.  What exact error message are you getting?

Comment: In my moment object I get `_d: Invalid Date` what version of moment do you use?

Comment: I'm using "2.11.0"

Comment: @DavinTryon Thanks updating moment did it. I had 2.10.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the [moment.js changelog](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md) that supporting a comma as the separator between seconds and milliseconds was added in version 2.11.0.  So, upgrade to at least that version.

That said, I would recommend using the current version, which is 2.12.0 as I write this.  In particular, 2.11.1 had some pretty important bugfixes, and 2.11.2 plugged a potential security risk.